# Reconstructing string from reference to a first byte in C#

Tags: c#

I'm using a function from a third party library that takes a file path via a reference to the first byte of the filename. I think that library is written in C/C++. Using a reference to the first byte  `DoJob` restores the file path. Is there a way to reconstruct the string from reference to a first byte in C# too, maybe using some unsafe code?

```
[DllImport("THIRDPARTY.dll")]
public static extern int DoJob(IntPtr handle, ref byte filePath);

string jobFilePath = "file.txt"
var filePathBytes = jobFilePath.ToByteArray();
var resCode = _api.DoJob(_handle, ref filePathBytes[0]);
```

**UPDATE**

I'm doing a unit test and mock `DoJob`. Without going too deep I would like to be able to restore string in unit test

```
var mockApi = new Mock<IApi>();
mockApi.Setup(_ => _.DoJob(It.IsAny<IntPtr>(), ref It.Ref<byte>.IsAny))
        .Returns(DoJobMock);

unsafe private int DoJobMock(IntPtr handle, ref byte filePath)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sure, `string` has a [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-string-ctor(system-sbyte*)) that takes a `sbyte*`, but why would you want to do that in the first place?

Comment: Usually, the type of file path passed in is `const char*`, although it is equivalent to `ref byte`, `string` should be better. Are you mistaken?

Comment: Just use string directly instead ref byte with marshal as LPStr attribute at this parameter

Comment: @Selvin, I updated my post why I want this. Is this achievable in `DoJobMock`?

Comment: just define `DoJob` as `public static extern int DoJob(IntPtr handle, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr) string filePath);` thean there would be no need for restoring the string as parameter would be the string